# Tomcat не открывает страницы если открыт из intellej idea

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Не могу найти ответ в интернете на подобный вопрос.
Tomcat запускается а страница не открывается , (если томкат запускать отдельно от  intellj idea то все работает и главная страница открывается )
Проэт создан вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом добавлен maven через add Framework support
потом 
при запуске tomkat  из idea в логах такие ошибки

---

10-Sep-2018 14:29:01.485 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
10-Sep-2018 14:29:01.485 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2018-09-10 02:29:01,504] Artifact A1:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.                                                                   ---------------------------------------------------

### 10-Sep-2018 14:29:01.485 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)

```
                                                                                   10-Sep-2018 14:29:01.485 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: Проверь работу Tomcat'a на минимальных настройках. Вот 
 по этому [линку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruG0SkRildo&t=7s). Затем дальше пойдем.

Comment: Да с минимальными настройками работает!! А почему же со Springom не работает.?

Comment: И еще вопрос! в ролике при создании проэта в архитектуре появляется и папка resourse  а у меня при таком же создании ее нет!       Почему?                                          
                       https://ibb.co/ghGkFU
https://ibb.co/jZWwN9

Comment: Как я понял на данный момент, нужно поменять путь для сервера, типа <Context 
  docBase="/opt/mywebapps/<yourApp>" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>          А как правильно это сделать не понимаю пробовал и на server.xml  and root.xml  в  папаке localhost  ничего не получается

Comment: [Вот](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-spring-apps-to-tomcat-without-webxml) почитай.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Нашел подобную статью в которой говориться "В данной статье я упакую приложение Spring MVC, написанное в  Eclipse и разверну его на  WebLogic Server.
Заметьте, если вы разворачиваете Spring MVC на других серверах, таких как Tomcat, Glassfish вам не нужно ничего менять на вашем исходном коде."    . Сейчас делал новое прилажение все работао пока не произвел mavenom   clean install

Comment: Ине кажется что это связано с Artifact   . я не совсем понимаю что это , если можно то простым языком объясните как это влияет на проэт, что оно делает ,? Может нужно создать правельный артифакт? Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: РЕШЕНИЕ: Всем кто не может решить эту проблемму. после clean install  mavena для tomcata при выборе артефакта наужно указать на скомпелированный файл war в папке target. СМОТРЕТЬ КАРТИНКУ https://ibb.co/eT74up

Comment: ТАЖЕ ОШИБКА: После очередного install  maven  опять сервер не запускается вообще. может кто подскаже что это за ошибки

Comment: 12-Sep-2018 12:16:16.403 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Ошибка настройки прослушивателя приложений класса [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: Как исправить ошибку прослушивателя приложений